# Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<T: P>' to expected argument type 'Binding<any P>'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, protocols

I have the following:

```
protocol SomeSelectorRow : CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
}

struct SomeSelector : View {
    @Binding var selectedRow: any SomeSelectorRow
    var rows: [any SomeSelectorRow]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(rows) { row in
                Button {
                    selectedRow = row
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Label(title: { Text(row.description) },
                              icon: { row == selectedRow ? imageA
                                                         : imageB })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
enum SomeEnum : String, SomeSelectorRow {
    case one = "one"
    case two = "two"
    case three = "three"

    var id: SomeEnum { self }

    var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

...

struct MyView : View {
    @Binding var selection: SomeEnum

    var body: some View {
        SomeSelector(selectedRow: $selection, rows: SomeEnum.allCases) <= ERROR
    }
}
```

On the indicated line I get the following error on `$selection`:

> Cannot convert value of type `Binding<SomeEnum>` to expected argument type `Binding<any SomeSelectorRow>`

I find this odd because `SomeEnum` is a `SomeSelectorRow`.

Why does this happen and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeEnum` is a concrete type. `any SomeSelectorRow` is not equivalent. You may want to make `SomeSelector` generic:

```
struct SomeSelector<T: SomeSelectorRow>: View {
    @Binding var selectedRow: T
    var rows: [T]
    // …
}
```

Then when you use `SomeEnum` it will produce an instance of `SomeSelector` specifically typed for `SomeEnum`.